# Win32Exeption: The operation completed successfully... graphics

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, exception, win32exception

Ive searched some fo a solution but not a single person shows a solution... I would appreciate if someone could explain why it occurs and how to solve it (in a simple way) :)

Occurs in same place all the time... a couple of minutes after i start the program.

```
private static Bitmap bmpScreenShot;
private static Graphics gfxScreenShot;
...
...

bmpScreenShot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
    Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
gfxScreenShot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenShot);
gfxScreenShot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
    Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, 
    CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy); // <-- Occurs here a while after ive started the application
```

It runs a couple of times (say 40-80 times) before this happens:

> Win32Exeption was unhandled: The operation completed successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i had to do `bmpScreenShot.Dispose();` and `gfxScreenShot.Dispose();`

Answer (score 1):

Before you go any further, create a try and catch statement:

```
try
{
    //Your code goes here
}
catch (Win32Exception e)
{
    //Handle the exception here, or use one of the following to find out what the issue is:
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Exception");
}
```

Comment: it ran one more time and only came to the bmpScreenShot = 
line saying (ArgumentExeption was unhandled |-| Parameter is not valid.)... any solution for this?... btw (does it matter if i get errors with the yellow triangle or can i just skip them?)

Comment: and when i add an exeption for that it happens everytime this code is called causing the code bmpScreenShot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
        Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb); to not beeing executed :S